# Автоматическое нажатие кнопки, при запуске определенного приложения

Tags: c#

Есть задача: когда пользователь на компьютере запускает некую программу, при запуске есть вероятность, что появится сообщение об ошибке, с единственной кнопкой "ОК".

Нужно сделать приложение, которое в запущенном бы состоянии следило, когда некое приложение запускается, и если в приложении появляется сообщение об ошибке, автоматически нажать кнопку "ОК" в этом сообщении.

С помощью чего можно реализовать данный функционал в Visual Studio на C#?

Comment: Несколько вариантов. - C - C++ - Assembler - И т.д. Выбрать можно любой.

Comment: FindWindow и SendMessage или PostMessage. тут наверное самое сложное это определить, это окно с ошибкой или нет)

Comment: @NMD, а если абстрагироваться от того, что окно с ошибкой, и просто нажимать на ОК в любом появившемся окне - проще станет?